# laplace transform of impulse function

Tags: calculus

The laplace tranform of the following function impulse function is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta(t).e^{-st}\,dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta(t)\,dt=1$$
(area under unit impulse is always 1)
$$=1.\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\,dt$$
$$=1.\frac{1}{S}$$
$$=\frac{1}{S}$$
but the correct answer is 1, I don't know why.

Comment: You can't integrate a factor only and take it out from the integral.

Comment: Also $\int_0^\infty \delta(t) e^{-st}dt$ is not a very good notation. You should say instead that  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) e^{-st}dt = e^{-st}|_{s=0} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that by the [sampling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation) of the delta function (which is actually a distribution)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)\delta(t-t_0)dt=f(t_0).$$

Comment: @reuns Yes, it is better to recall that.

Comment: To make it clear, you can define it as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) f(t)dt \overset{def}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|t| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon} f(t)dt$